# How can I redirect a user from the login page to the signup page in a different app Django?

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-urls

So, I have been trying to do this problem for a couple of days, but I seem to be having no luck, in actually solving it.

For my side-project, I am creating a student grade management system in Django, and the problem that I am getting is that everytime the user clicks on the signup button on the homepage/login page, I get an error, because I haven't re-routed the user successfully. Specifically, the error I get is that it says, Page not Found.

The page that I am trying to re-route the user to is in another app. So, I'm trying to route the user to the base url of that app, which from there, it will pop open a view.

Here is the code for my urls.py on the loginpage/homepage (App1)

```
from django.urls import re_path
from django.shortcuts import redirect
# import signUpPage.views as signupview
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^$', views.login, name='login'),
    # re_path('signUpPage', signupview.register, name='signUpPage')
    # re_path('')
]
```

Here is the code for my forms.py on the loginpage/homepage (App1)

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Fieldset, Layout


class loginForm(forms.Form):
    UserName = forms.CharField(
        label="Username",
        help_text="Please enter your username",
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Username"}),
        required=False
    )

    Password = forms.CharField(
        label="Password",
        help_text="Enter your password",
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Password"}),
        required=False
    )
```

Here is the code for my views.py on the loginpage/homepage (App2)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponseRedirect
from . forms import loginForm
from django.urls import re_path
from signUpPage.views import register
# from .models import <Insert whatever it is you want to import, but it might not be nexessary>


def login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        redirect('signUpPage')
        if request.POST.get("signup"):
            register()
    else:
        form = loginForm(request.GET)
        return render(request, 'homePage/homePage.html', {"form": form})
```

Here is the html for the loginpage/homepage (App1)

```
{% load static%}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}</title>

    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{% static 'homePage/favicon.png' %}">
    {% load bootstrap4 %}
    <link href="../../static/homePage/homePage.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="homePage-background"> <!-- animation area-->
        <svg class="container-sm" width="25%" height="760" style="position:absolute; margin-left: 35%; margin-top:35px">
            <rect id="loginRect" width="100%" height="100%" rx="40px" ry="40px" style="fill: cornflowerblue; stroke: pink; stroke-opacity: 0.0; stroke-width: 3px; "/>
            <foreignObject height="760" width="100%">
                <div class="loginpage-form">
                    {% block content %}
                    <form action="homePage/forms.py" method="post">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        {{forms|crispy}}
                        {% for field in form %}
                            <div class="fields">
                                <div class="label">{{field}}</div>
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-success" id="loginButton" formmethod="post">Login</button>
                        <button type="submit" name="signup" class="btn btn-success" id="signUpButton" formmethod="get">Sign Up</button>
                    </form>
                    {% endblock %}
                </div>
            </foreignObject>
        </svg>

        <ul class="animation"> <!-- box area-->
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the code for my urls.py on the signuppage (App2)

```
from django.urls import re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    re_path('^$', views.register, name='register'),
]
```

Here is the html for the signup page (App2)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../static/signUpPage/signUpPage.css" type="text/css"/>
    {% load bootstrap4 %}
    <title>{% block title %}SignUp{% endblock %} </title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="backGround">
        <div class="container-sm">
            <h2>Sign Up</h2>
        </div>

        <div id="inputs">
            <img src="../../static/signUpPage/SignUp-Person.png" alt="Signup Person Image" id="image">
            <p id="inputText">Please enter your Email Address,<br/> Username, and Password.</p>
            <div class="form-group">
                {% block content %}
                <form method="post">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ forms|crispy}}
                    {% for field in form %}
                        <div class="fields">
                            <label for="{{ field.id_for_label }}" class="label">{{field.html_name}}</label>
                            {{field}}
                        </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="signup-button" value="user-credentials">Sign Up</button>
                </form>
                {% endblock %}
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

EDIT: Here is the settings.py file

```
"""
Django settings for GradingSystem project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.8.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'h#yn1kty8in#qx#f#y4k6n$mzyc6q9o$ovlt5p=u=974ny@nq-'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'signUpPage.apps.SignuppageConfig',
    'homePage.apps.HomepageConfig',
    'grades.apps.GradesConfig',
    'newcourse.apps.NewcourseConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap4',
    'crispy_forms',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'GradingSystem.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'homePage', 'templates', 'homePage'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'signUpPage', 'templates', 'signUpPage'),
                 os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'grades', 'templates', 'grades')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'GradingSystem.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'student_accounts',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
        'USER': 'root',
        #This asks me for my password on runtime, because I do not feel comfortable writing my password here.
        'PASSWORD': input("Password:"),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
```

Answer (score 0):

in your `urls.py` file, you can add a constant with the name `app_name="app_name"` and in your HTML link or button, you can simply use the `url` tag like `{% url app_name:path_name %}`.

It tells the Django which specific `urls.py` file you are talking about.

Comment: So, this is for the urls.py, which contains the urls for all the different apps, right?

Comment: yes add a different app_name for each app. This way Django will be able to figure out what specific app you are talking about.